# Can I replace hotend on Lulzbot Mini 2 with upcoming E3D Hermes?

Tags: hotend, lulzbot, e3d-hemera

I've seen articles about the Hermes (now rebranded to Hemera) hotend coming soon from E3D, and was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to replace the stock Aerostruder on Lulzbot Mini 2 with it. The Aero has been giving me some issues and the printer is currently unusable... I've been printing for a few years but am still pretty new to mods so I don't really know what I'm doing there.

Comment: we don't know the final mounting dimensions yet and it would help if you'd tell us the mounting of the Lulzbot hotend (best a Photo with a ruler and/or the mounting hole pattern to the carriage).

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in the title of your question. If it is solved, then there must be an answer! So if the answer hasn't been written down, add your own answer and accept that answer after 48 hours or vote and accept an existing answer. Please note that SE sites are not forums of threaded messages but a structured question and answers sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, E3D has a guide ["LulzBot Taz6 Hemera Upgrade"](https://e3d-online.dozuki.com/Guide/LulzBot+Taz6+Hemera+Upgrade/123) if you'd like to make your own.

The upgrade requires you to print parts beforehand which are found [here](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4008893); note that:

> We recommend printing the Hemera Mount in PETG, and the Fan Duct in ABS/ ASA or another high-temperature material.
>
> Use an infill percentage of 25 % or higher.

The Hemera (the new name for the Hermes) toolheads are also available for purchase, e.g. [here](https://itworks3d.com/product/it-works-3d-e3d-hemera-toolhead-for-lulzbot-printers/).